# InnoSetup not uninstalling anything

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

I'm facing a weird issue on a customer site.

When running uninstall, nothing happens.

I asked for log files, here what's happening (launching unins000.exe  /log="C:\uninstall.log") :

```
2017-04-25 13:52:29.156   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC-07:00)
2017-04-25 13:52:29.156   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.5 (a)
2017-04-25 13:52:29.156   Original Uninstall EXE: C:\Program Files\XXXXX\XXXXX YYYYY V7.0 R1\unins000.exe
2017-04-25 13:52:29.156   Uninstall DAT: C:\Program Files\XXXXX\XXXXX YYYYY V7.0 R1\unins000.dat
2017-04-25 13:52:29.156   Uninstall command line: /SECONDPHASE="C:\Program Files\XXXXX\XXXXX YYYYY V7.0 R1\unins000.exe" /FIRSTPHASEWND=$A0302 /log="C:\uninstall.log"
2017-04-25 13:52:29.156   Windows version: 6.1.7601 SP1  (NT platform: Yes)
2017-04-25 13:52:29.156   64-bit Windows: No
2017-04-25 13:52:29.156   Processor architecture: x86
2017-04-25 13:52:29.156   User privileges: Administrative
2017-04-25 13:52:29.187   64-bit install mode: No
2017-04-25 13:52:29.187   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\is-UFQFQ.tmp
2017-04-25 13:52:29.187   Message box (Yes/No):
                          Are you sure you want to completely remove XXXXX YYYYY and all of its components?
2017-04-25 13:52:29.187   User chose No.
2017-04-25 13:52:29.203   Log closed.
```

It seems that "No" has been clicked as soon as box appeared.

Does someone has any clue of what's going on here?

Thanks

Gérald

Answer (score -1):

User clicked No, that is all.

User selected not to continue the uninstallation => he does not want to uninstall the application.

Comment: I find it unlikely that the user managed to click *No* the same millisecond the prompt appeared. + The log was send on demand to investigate the issue. The user is hopefully not that stupid to click *No* and wonder, why the installation does not proceed.

Comment: Yes, I agree - the times are exactly the same (13:52:29.187) but still I think clicking No is the reason. And do not believe there is some bug in Inno causing random No clicking. There may be something stuck in keyboard so 'N' is pressed or some other software causing this trouble, or some Tab/focus/Enter related problem which is in my opinion the source of clicking the No.

Comment: Can you rebuild the installer with latest Inno Setup version (5.5.9)? This may be bug in Inno Setup, so we need to exclude this.